# How to get the origin of a request to my API?

Tags: php, authentication, api-design

I'm writing an API. I just want certain URL addresses to access this API. How do I find the URL addresses that try to use the API?

I want to know the URL addresses that try to access the API server address with `file_get_contents` yada-like methods.

Comment: _Note:_ What you want is the IP-addresses, not URL addresses. Either way, you have an answer explaining what to do.

Comment: If you have an API that you need to restrict access to you need to setup an authentication mechanism like OAuth or JWT. Don't try to take shortcuts around security.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @apokryfos how can I do it. Are you sharing Link? Thanks :))

Comment: For example you can use a library like https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

Answer (score 0):

There is an array in PHP named `$_SERVER` which gives you various useful information about the request, including all HTTP headers, request type, IP address, browser User-Agent and more. Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for details. To access for example the IP address that accessed your API, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Be more informative. Which variable did you use? What kind of result did you get? I can't read your mind (or screen) even if I wanted to.

Comment: Api adress: api.example.com/test.php Client: blabla.com
I'm trying to find url addresses that use API. Example: blabla.com. 
I apologize for using the English language poorly. I'm learning new english

Comment: I already figured that out. Did you try checking the answer I gave you? You can get the IP by checking `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: I am trying to license the domain and therefore I need to find the domain address.

Comment: @Andy I do realize that but if the request doesn't contain a `Host:` header in the request, he'll get nothing. Remote address will always be filled. But actually there is a bigger problem. When using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` anyone can make a request with `Host: allowed-one.com` and will be let in to use the API. This is pretty much equal to no security as all, anyone can bypass it if he knows at least one allowed domain.

Comment: `REMOTE_HOST` will also not work if you don't have `HostnameLookups On` in your `httpd.conf`. It also uses REMOTE_ADDR and just does reverse DNS lookup, so you get no additional information that way.